# RHEL openssl conflicts

Tags: rhel, openssl

I am stuck installing PHP 5.5 (to support wordpress) on RHEL  6.3 (Santiago), I think the server was not set up correctly (contractor) and I have ended up with a copy openssl from ius as opposed to the base linux repo.

the error I am dealing with is as follows:

```
/usr/lib64/libcrypto.so.1.0.1e from install of openssl-1.0.1e-30.el6_6.4.x86_64 conflicts with file from package openssl10-libs-1.0.1e-1.ius.el6.x86_64
```

I tried to remove the ius version, but there are nearly 40 dependencies on it - some of which look important (wget, python, openssh).

What is the best course of action here? Should I rebuild from scratch OR remove the dependencies and reinstall?

---

Gareth I gave it a try.  For some reason it doesn't think openssl is installed from yum:

```
> remove openssl
Setting up Remove Process
No Match for argument: openssl
Package(s) openssl available, but not installed.
```

but i tried the remainder anyway:

```
> install openssl                    
Setting up Install Process

> run

--> Running transaction check
---> Package openssl.x86_64 0:1.0.1e-30.el6_6.4 will be installed
--> Finished Dependency Resolution

====================================================================================================================================================================
 Package                          Arch                            Version                                       Repository                                     Size
====================================================================================================================================================================
Installing:
 openssl                          x86_64                          1.0.1e-30.el6_6.4                             rhel-x86_64-server-6                          1.5 M

Transaction Summary
====================================================================================================================================================================
Install       1 Package(s)

Total size: 1.5 M
Installed size: 0  
Is this ok [y/N]: y
Downloading Packages:
Running rpm_check_debug
Running Transaction Test
Error: Transaction Check Error:
  file /usr/lib64/libcrypto.so.1.0.1e from install of openssl-1.0.1e-30.el6_6.4.x86_64 conflicts with file from package openssl10-libs-1.0.1e-1.ius.el6.x86_64
  file /usr/lib64/libssl.so.1.0.1e from install of openssl-1.0.1e-30.el6_6.4.x86_64 conflicts with file from package openssl10-libs-1.0.1e-1.ius.el6.x86_64
  file /usr/lib64/openssl/engines/lib4758cca.so from install of openssl-1.0.1e-30.el6_6.4.x86_64 conflicts with file from package openssl10-libs-1.0.1e-1.ius.el6.x86_64
  file /usr/lib64/openssl/engines/libaep.so from install of openssl-1.0.1e-30.el6_6.4.x86_64 conflicts with file from package openssl10-libs-1.0.1e-1.ius.el6.x86_64
  file /usr/lib64/openssl/engines/libatalla.so from install of openssl-1.0.1e-30.el6_6.4.x86_64 conflicts with file from package openssl10-libs-1.0.1e-1.ius.el6.x86_64
  file /usr/lib64/openssl/engines/libcapi.so from install of openssl-1.0.1e-30.el6_6.4.x86_64 conflicts with file from package openssl10-libs-1.0.1e-1.ius.el6.x86_64
  file /usr/lib64/openssl/engines/libchil.so from install of openssl-1.0.1e-30.el6_6.4.x86_64 conflicts with file from package openssl10-libs-1.0.1e-1.ius.el6.x86_64
  file /usr/lib64/openssl/engines/libcswift.so from install of openssl-1.0.1e-30.el6_6.4.x86_64 conflicts with file from package openssl10-libs-1.0.1e-1.ius.el6.x86_64
  file /usr/lib64/openssl/engines/libgmp.so from install of openssl-1.0.1e-30.el6_6.4.x86_64 conflicts with file from package openssl10-libs-1.0.1e-1.ius.el6.x86_64
  file /usr/lib64/openssl/engines/libnuron.so from install of openssl-1.0.1e-30.el6_6.4.x86_64 conflicts with file from package openssl10-libs-1.0.1e-1.ius.el6.x86_64
  file /usr/lib64/openssl/engines/libpadlock.so from install of openssl-1.0.1e-30.el6_6.4.x86_64 conflicts with file from package openssl10-libs-1.0.1e-1.ius.el6.x86_64
  file /usr/lib64/openssl/engines/libsureware.so from install of openssl-1.0.1e-30.el6_6.4.x86_64 conflicts with file from package openssl10-libs-1.0.1e-1.ius.el6.x86_64
  file /usr/lib64/openssl/engines/libubsec.so from install of openssl-1.0.1e-30.el6_6.4.x86_64 conflicts with file from package openssl10-libs-1.0.1e-1.ius.el6.x86_64

Error Summary
-------------
```

Comment: It looks like IUS [contains yum-plugin-replace](https://iuscommunity.org/pages/IUSClientUsageGuide.html) You might try using that to see if that lets you just switch the package over to the base repo version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try `yum`'s shell to carry out the change as one transaction:-

```
# yum shell
>
> remove <package>
> repo disable <repo ID of IUS>
> install <package>
> run
```

Alternatively, if your `yum` is modern enough, you could use it's `swap` command.

Comment: thanks Gareth, if you could see my update - for some reason yum doesn't think openssl is installed.

Comment: @akaphenom - but `openssl-libs` is installed.  Try replacing the current with the the non-IUS version using the above procedure.

Comment: exactly the point of my confusion, the file is obviously there and other packages are dependent on it BUT yum remove openssl: "No Match for argument: openssl" - i did try your procedure, and updated my original post with the output.

Comment: What openssl packages are installed? Just `openssl-libs` or also `openssl` itself? It looks like you have a version installed that has openssl split in multiple packages and you're trying to replace it with an openssl that has everything in one package.

Comment: @akaphenom - If I understand your predicament correctly, I think you need to replace the IUS version of `openssl-libs` with the non-IUS version first, then install `openssl`. You cannot remove `openssl-libs` as it's such a dangerous act that `yum` protects itself from destruction. However, you should be able to replace it with the non-IUS one. Once that's done, you should be able to install `openssl` itself.

Comment: hmmm - so you are suggesting to find and download the libraries, and copy them into place FIRST.  Then do the yum install of openssl...

Comment: @akaphenom - No. I'm suggesting you try the `yum shell` procedure to remove `openssl-libs` (not `openssl`), disable the IUS repo and finally install `openssl-libs` (from the main repo as the IUS one will be disabled); all as one transaction. The single transaction should (hopefully) not cause `yum` to want to uninstall half of your important packages.

Comment: wait i am new here (being linux/rhel) didn't realize openssl-libs and openssl were different packages!